# Не показывает рекламу AdMob в приложении

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, мобильные-приложения, реклама

Решил создать первое простое приложение на Андроиде, добавил рекламу AdMob, но после выгрузки на плей маркет реклама перестала показываться. 
В коде тестовые баннеры заменил на настоящие полученные в личном кабинете AdMob, также убрал пометку об тестовом устройсве,после в превью layout все отображаеться, но после создания abb файла и загрузки в маркет реклама больше не отображается. Читал, что должно пройти какое-то время, прежде чем будет отображаться реклама, но спустя неделю рекламы еще нет. Не могу понять что не так. В плей стор пишет, что реклама есть в приложении, а на деле нет.

И часть кода в layout

```js
MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-my-program-id")
adView_settings.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
```

И xml

```xml
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView_settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-my-banner-id">
```

Comment: попробуйте ads:adSize="BANNER", создайте release версию и запустите

Comment: Вы в `Manifest` добавляли - `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>` ?. Если да то проверьте точно ли вы добавили его в `<Application>  </Application>`